# write Error: Broken Pipe in C using execlp

Tags: c, unix

I have issues creating simple C program which takes arguments from command line, the last argument is path to the file. Program runs `cat` command on given file, and then runs tr on the result of cat. Tr gets arguments from command line(other than the last argument). I am getting errors: 
Missing operand.
write error: Broken Pipe.
I am not sure where the mistake is...

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WRITE_END 1
#define READ_END 0

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("\nPROVIDE AN ARGUMENT\n");
        return 1;
    }
    const char * file = argv[argc - 1];
    char ** args = calloc(argc - 2, sizeof(char*));
    for( int i = 1; i<argc-2; i++){
        args[i - 1 ] = argv[i];
    }

    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    pid_t child;

    if((child = fork()) == -1)return 2;

    if(child == 0){
        dup2(fd[WRITE_END], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[READ_END]);
        close(fd[WRITE_END]);
        execlp("cat", "cat", file, (char*)NULL);
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        dup2(fd[READ_END], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[WRITE_END]);
        close(fd[READ_END]);
        execlp("tr", "tr", *args, (char*)NULL);
        exit(1);
    }

    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
    wait(0);
    wait(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `dup(fd[0]);` This doesn't do what you think it does. You may want to research `man dup2`,

Comment: Your `args` variable is messed up; you are effectively copying an array of `char *` into an array of `char`.  This seems to be a misguided attempt to make `execlp` work, when what you really want is `execvp`.

Comment: Now it looks lie this ```if(child == 0){
        dup2(fd[WRITE_END], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[READ_END]);
        close(fd[WRITE_END]);
        execlp("cat", "cat", file, (char*)NULL);
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        dup2(STDIN_FILENO, fd[READ_END]);
        close(fd[WRITE_END]);
        close(fd[READ_END]);
        execlp("tr", "tr", *args, (char*)NULL);
        exit(1);
    }
```
I think that there are still some issues with the pipe. This is realy blurry topic for me :((

Comment: It's really hard to read code in comments.  Please edit your question to include the new version.

Comment: There's no problem with how you handled the pipe.  The problems were with allocation and copying of args and uses of exec functions.  See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here that are keeping you from getting this to work.  First, as mentioned by Nate Eldredge in a comment, there are problems with the allocation and copying of the all-but-last arguments to variable `args`.  Second, your use of execlp has a slight problem in that the arguments should include an extra argument corresponding to the name of the program run (not the same as the file opened as the executable, lots of people get confused about this point).  Third, as also mentioned by Nate, you need to call execvp in the branch of the if-else corresponding to the parent process (the "else" branch).  Its second argument will need to be an array of *pointers* to character, the last of which is `NULL`.

So taking these one at a time.  First, you need to allocate `argc` slots for `args` to use it in something like the way you intend:

```
char ** args = calloc(argc, sizeof(char*));
memcpy(args, argv, sizeof(char*)*(argc -1));
```

The first line allocates an array of character pointers the same size as the arg. list.  The second line copies all but the last pointer in `argv` to the corresponding location in `args` and leaves the last one as `NULL` (`calloc` initialized the storage for it to be zero, and you need the last pointer in `args` to be a null pointer if you're going to pass it to execvp, which you will).  Note that you're not duplicating all of the storage under argv, just the pointers in the first dimension (remember:  `argv[0]` is a pointer and `argv[0][0]` is the first character in the program name).

Note that your use of `close` and `dup` was fine.  I don't know why anyone objected to that unless they forgot that allocating a file descriptor always takes the lowest-numbered descriptor that is unused.  That's about the most important thing about descriptor tables as originally used in UNIX.

Next, the call to `execlp` that overlays the child process created by `fork` with "cat" is missing an argument.  It should be:

```
execlp("cat", "cat", file, (char*)NULL);
```

That extra `"cat"` in there is the value cat will receive when it enters `main()` as argv[0].  You're probably noticing that this looks like you could lie about the name of the program you're running with the exec__ functions, and you can (but you can't completely hide having done it).

Finally, that second execlp call.  You can't pass arguments through as if they were typed on the command line, in one big string:  exec in any form doesn't use a shell to invoke the other program and it's not going to parse the command line for you.  In addition, the way you were (apparently, if I've read your intent correctly) trying to concatenate the argument strings was also not right (see above comments about `args` allocation and the `memcpy` call).  You have to break out individual arguments and pass them to it.  So if you have an array of pointer to character and the last one is `NULL`, like you'll have in `args` after the changes I indicated for allocating and copying data, then you can just pass `args` to `execvp`:

```
execvp("tr", args);
```

These aren't huge errors and a lot of people make these kinds of mistakes when starting out with manipulating the argument list and using the fork and exec functions.  A lot of people make mistakes trying to use a pipe between parent and child processes but you seem to have gotten that part right.

One last thing:  the lines downstream in execution from the exec__ calls only get executed if there's an error performing the actual replacement of the running program with the new one.  Errors on the command line of "cat" or "tr", for example, won't cause exec__ to fail.  Errors like lack of permission to execute the file given as the first argument or absence of the file *will* cause the exec__ functions to fail.  Unless exec returns an error, nothing downstream of the exec call is executed in the process in which it is executed (a successful exec never returns).